# Mailchimp playground not showing campaigns inside campaign-folder

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a mailchimp campaign folder **Production** with 5 campaigns inside
[image]

If I call **campaign-folders** API via playground, it turns out that the campaign count is **5** so all good
[image]

Now if I call the **campaigns** sub-resource via playground, it returned only **3 campaigns**
[image]
You can see on the console that there are no other filters.

I am also having this issue on my node app w/c calls http GET `MAILCHIMP_V3_API_URL/campaigns` w/c also does not return the campaigns that are not showing up on **Production** campaign folder,
W/c is why I'm trying to do the API call on playground to clear some of my assumptions.

Any ideas why this happen? Will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: guy, you helped me, i needed to know Playground to solve my problems. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome.. i'm happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an awesome conversation with the tech support & the key point here is that some campaigns will fall under **/automations** endpoint.

To determine w/c of these campaigns will be accessible under **/automations** endpoint, check the campaign list & notice the double-arrow(refresh) icon before the campaign title
[image]